# Как существительные, которые не имеют единственного числа, сочетаются с числительными?

Tags: числительные

Встретилось мне в одной книге такое сочетание: "две скрипучие качели". Озадачило это меня. Неужели это правильно?

Answer (score 4):

Нет, здесь либо ошибка, либо имелось в виду просторечное "качель".

В отношении подобных существительных (pluralia tantum) возможно согласование по парадигме множественного числа - двое суток, трое ворот и т.д. Но надо иметь в виду, что использование этой формы ограничено малыми величинами (по разным рекомендациям ограничивается вариантами от "двое до пятеро" до "от двое до двенадцатеро"), и к тому же не всегда стилистически оправдано. В силу последнего даже "двое качелей" представляется сомнительным.
В строгой или канцелярской речи лучше "две штуки качелей", "две единицы качелей" и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: двое скрипучих качелей.

Для обозначения количества существительных,   употребляемых только во множественном числе  (pluralia tantum), а также обозначающих парные предметы, используются собирательные числительные, например: двое ножниц, четверо суток, трое ботинок (три пары ботинок).

Интересно отметить, что собирательные числительные используются только в И.-В. падеже, а в других падежах они заменяются на количественные числительные: двое качелей - двух качелей, двое ворот - к двум воротам.

Например: Из трех качелей двое качелей заняты.